# The social media icons on my wordpress homepage are displaying properly using FontAwesome on OceanWP theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the OceanWP theme and on the homepage the social media icons are not displaying. They are showing fine on the header and footer of every other page except the homepage.

They appear like this on the header of the homepage: https://prnt.sc/phrd7h

and like this on the footer of the homepage: https://prnt.sc/phrdef

After searching on google I found a solution which advised me to paste the code:

```
.fa {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

in the custom css section of the dashboard. I did this and it appears to have helped as the icons are now showing on the homepage but they look a little thicker than the icons on the other pages and are quite blurry. They now appear like this:

https://prnt.sc/phrdjm

https://prnt.sc/phrdnk

(...also on the footer of the homepage the vimeo icon is still not showing.)

But on the other pages they appear to look much more clear. They look like this:

https://prnt.sc/phrdsi

https://prnt.sc/phre7j

Does anybody know how I can make the icons look clearer on the homepage footer and header?

Comment: plz check the OceanWP theme plugins, wheather font awesome plugin is added..

Comment: This might because of the version issue! Check which version they are using and which one you're using! Same problem i faced and it get resolved when i changed the version

Comment: Hey nafiza rashid, Manikandan2811 thank you both so much! I downloaded the font awesome 5 plugin and now it is working perfectly:) thanks again!